# Updating ObjC app on XCode 9

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode9

I recently updated our ObjC app on XCode 9. Everything was ok (I even updated to iPhone X new layout), there has been just an issue in one of the viewControllers (built in IB). This viewController, which shows a tableView with news, can be accessed from 2 sources:

1. From appDelegate if a Push Notification informs about new news. In this case, a right navBarButton is unhidden so the user can dismiss the view
2. From a specific section, where a normal back button is used

When I try to open the viewController from the second case, the app crashes with the next message:

> 2017-10-17 12:53:26.747396-0500 verifica[17299:1270771] *** Assertion failure in -[_UIButtonBarButtonVisualProviderIOS _addConstraintsForBackgroundImageWithOffset:isBackButton:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3694.4.18/_UIButtonBarButtonVisualProviderIOS.m:485
>   2017-10-17 12:53:26.855489-0500 verifica[17299:1270771] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '_UIButtonBarButtonVisualProviderIOS cannot have a background without any content'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba151cb **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>     1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010af48f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
>     2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba1a362 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
>     3   Foundation                          0x0000000106a22089 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
>     4   UIKit                               0x000000010860cd92 -[_UIButtonBarButtonVisualProviderIOS _addConstraintsForBackgroundImageWithOffset:isBackButton:] + 1079
>     5   UIKit                               0x000000010860c903 -[_UIButtonBarButtonVisualProviderIOS _configureBackgroundForButton:fromBarButtonItem:isBackButton:] + 1060
>     6   UIKit                               0x0000000108610610 -[_UIButtonBarButtonVisualProviderIOS configureButton:fromBarButtonItem:] + 2630
>     7   UIKit                               0x000000010860dcaf -[_UIButtonBarButtonVisualProviderIOS configureButton:withAppearanceDelegate:fromBarItem:] + 148
>     8   UIKit                               0x0000000107ff3096 -[_UIButtonBarButton _configureFromBarItem:appearanceDelegate:isBackButton:] + 86
>     9   UIKit                               0x0000000107ff2c20 -[_UIButtonBarButton configureFromBarItem:withAppearanceDelegate:] + 53
>     10  UIKit                               0x00000001085a2049 -[_UIButtonBar _updatedViewForBarButtonItem:withView:] + 338
>     11  UIKit                               0x00000001085a0add __32-[_UIButtonBar _newGroupLayout:]_block_invoke + 82
>     12  UIKit                               0x00000001085960d3 -[_UIButtonBarItemLayout _updateItemView] + 53
>     13  UIKit                               0x000000010859667c -[_UIButtonBarItemLayout _configure] + 40
>     14  UIKit                               0x000000010859518f -[_UIButtonBarLayout configure] + 60
>     15  UIKit                               0x00000001085952d9 -[_UIButtonBarLayout addLayoutViews:] + 49
>     16  UIKit                               0x000000010859864e -[_UIButtonBarItemGroupLayout _iterateConfiguredLayouts:] + 228
>     17  UIKit                               0x000000010859872f -[_UIButtonBarItemGroupLayout _addLayoutViews:] + 116
>     18  UIKit                               0x000000010859523d -[_UIButtonBarLayout addLayoutViews:layoutGuides:constraintsToActivate:constraintsToDeactivate:] + 111
>     19  UIKit                               0x00000001085a1264 -[_UIButtonBar _layoutBar] + 1833
>     20  UIKit                               0x00000001085a3b44 -[_UIButtonBarStackView updateConstraints] + 48
>     21  UIKit                               0x000000010870d8b6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _sendUpdateConstraintsIfNecessaryForSecondPass:] + 161
>     22  UIKit                               0x000000010870ded2 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 1296
>     23  UIKit                               0x000000010870dd51 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 911
>     24  Foundation                          0x00000001069acde1 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 131
>     25  UIKit                               0x000000010870e703 __100-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke + 90
>     26  UIKit                               0x000000010870cf61 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 104
>     27  UIKit                               0x000000010870e272 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 160
>     28  UIKit                               0x000000010870f38c -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 401
>     29  UIKit                               0x0000000107c671b6 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 1517
>     30  UIKit                               0x00000001084a74cd -[_UINavigationBarTransitionContextPush _prepareContentView] + 130
>     31  UIKit                               0x00000001084a8b2b -[_UINavigationBarTransitionContextPush prepare] + 133
>     32  UIKit                               0x000000010878d15a -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS _performAnimationWithTransitionCompletion:transition:] + 740
>     33  UIKit                               0x0000000107cb60b6 -[UINavigationBar _pushNavigationItem:transitionAssistant:] + 359
>     34  UIKit                               0x0000000107cb58e2 -[UINavigationBar _pushNavigationItemUsingCurrentTransition:] + 368
>     35  UIKit                               0x0000000107cb5a47 -[UINavigationBar pushNavigationItem:animated:] + 179
>     36  UIKit                               0x0000000107cb02cf -[UINavigationBar _performUpdatesIgnoringLock:] + 47
>     37  UIKit                               0x0000000107cb5b51 -[UINavigationBar _pushNavigationItem:transition:] + 152
>     38  UIKit                               0x0000000107d97f37 __71-[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:]_block_invoke + 371
>     39  UIKit                               0x0000000107d9812c __71-[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:]_block_invoke.1981 + 114
>     40  UIKit                               0x0000000107d92bcf __98-[UINavigationController _shouldSkipHostedRefreshControlUpdateSchedulingDeferredUpdateIfNecessary]_block_invoke + 18
>     41  UIKit                               0x0000000107d94b25 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 1343
>     42  UIKit                               0x0000000107d95b90 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 115
>     43  UIKit                               0x0000000107fec2ae -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
>     44  UIKit                               0x0000000128bc4a9f -[UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility layoutSubviews] + 42
>     45  UIKit                               0x0000000107c7c551 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1331
>     46  QuartzCore                          0x000000010773a4ba -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 153
>     47  QuartzCore                          0x000000010773e5a9 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 401
>     48  QuartzCore                          0x00000001076c71cd _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 365
>     49  QuartzCore                          0x00000001076f2ae4 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 500
>     50  UIKit                               0x0000000107bd8687 _afterCACommitHandler + 272
>     51  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b9b7db7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
>     52  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b9b7d0e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
>     53  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b99c324 __CFRunLoopRun + 1572
>     54  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b99ba89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
>     55  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010f3fd9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
>     56  UIKit                               0x0000000107badd30 UIApplicationMain + 159
>     57  verifica                            0x0000000103ce9f0f main + 111
>     58  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ac32d81 start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

The app worked fine before XCode 9. I've run it in the simulator (with iOS, 10.3, 10.3.1 & 11) and on an iPhone with iOS 11, and crashes all the time for case 2.

I've searched several of the terms referred in the console, but the only similar was http://www.cocoachina.com/bbs/read.php?tid-1726269.html, I used Google Translate and one guy says: "mainly due to the navigantionBarItem picture and the location of the text caused by the offset".

As I said the view was built in IB with a normal Navigation Controller, no offset in the button. The only difference with other similar viewControllers that work fine is the right navBarButton that is shown in case 1 but not in case 2 with the next code in viewDidLoad:

```
if (self.fromAppDelegate) {
        self.doneButton.title = @"Cerrar";
        self.doneButton.enabled = YES;
    } else self.doneButton.enabled = NO;
```

I'm sure its gonna be an easy solution but right now I can't find it. I hope someone can help me.

- Update
  These are this button's configuration in IB:
  [InterfaceBuilder: Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYSl9.png)

Comment: If you comment out the `doneButton` adjustments, does the crash go away?

Comment: Yes, same error

Comment: I meant, no, it doesn't go away, it's the same error

Comment: So, nothing to do with the code you posted, right?

Comment: I don't think so, as I said, it was created in IB and that's the only code for that button. I'll update the question to show it's configuration in IB, but there's nothing special about it, that's what confuses me the most.

Answer (score 1):

OK, when I was checking the configuration for the button in IB, I noticed that its width (Size Inspector) was zero. I changed it to 80 so, the button shows now in the preview. I also, in Attributes Inspector, changed it from Custom system item to Done and in code added the next line for the else statement:

`self.doneButton.title = @"";`

It worked, the app didn't crash anymore, but the button, if not enabled, was visible as Done all the time which is not what I want (the code above didn't work because it was set as System Button, duh). So, I change it back to Custom and delete the default title aaaand... everything was as before (check image in the question), but the app still works. What? Well, not everything was as before: the code above was the only change. If I commented the line, the app crashes again.

I don't know if it's a bug or a new requirement, but I hope it useful for someone (I knew the answer was gonna be easy).